# How can I include a text file as part of an Android Install?

Tags: android

I need to be able to include a text file with my Android Install
so that I can read and parse it as needed.

It's about 57 KB bytes, so I probably couldn't do it as a "String"
resource.  Do I try to add it as some kind of Resource?
It says that "Raw" can't take strings.

I could do an HTTP GET to get a similar XML file, but that's
way bigger, 900 KB, my file is a greatly condensed version of the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Add it in the `assets` folder (NOT in `raw`). You can find info on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162623/how-to-use-assets-in-android) about loading assets (specifically text files). [This blog](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/) goes a little more in-depth.